# Read dynamically updated attribute value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a situation over here. I'm writing this situation in a chronology.

1. Assume that there are an `input[type=number`] and a button.
2. When the button is clicked, it will change the attribute value `(data-oldval="")` to the current value of the input number.
3. The next time I click the button, it supposed to add the current value in the input with the number in the `data-oldval` attribute.
4. But the problem is, I can't read the newly updated attribute value.

To make the situation clearer, I included the code snippet below. I hope that anybody here can help me with this.

```js
var response = $('.response');

$('body').on('click', '.btn', function() {
  var btn = $(this),
    t = btn.parent('.dummy'),
    n = t.find('input[type=number]'),
    val = n.val(),
    oldval = n.data('oldval');

  n.attr('data-oldval', val+oldval);

  response.text(n.data('oldval'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dummy">
  <input type="number" value="1" data-oldval="0">
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Add</button>
</div>

<div class="response"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with point 3? Add the current value to what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues; you need to retrieve the value using `data('oldval')`, not `attr()`, and you also need to convert `val()` to an integer so it can be added to the old value. Try this:

```js
var response = $('.response');

$('body').on('click', '.btn', function() {
  var btn = $(this),
    t = btn.parent('.dummy'),
    n = t.find('input[type=number]'),
    val = parseInt(n.val(), 10),
    oldval = n.data('oldval');

  n.data('oldval', val + oldval);

  response.text(n.data('oldval'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dummy">
  <input type="number" value="1" data-oldval="0">
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Add</button>
</div>

<div class="response"></div>
```

Comment: please, about retrieving value, don't also attr() can do it? It is just good practice to use data()

Comment: `attr()` can retrieve `data-*` attributes too - and it's fine to do that, but there is a crucial difference. `attr()` gets the attribute from the DOM as it was *loaded*. `data()` gets the value from jQuery's internal cache as it *currently is*. For example, if the value was `0` and I add `5` to it. `attr('data-oldval')` would return `0`, `data('oldval')` would return `5`.

Comment: thank you, your are informative as usual. Was asking myself the question for a long time

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the number entered into the input or it will be returned as a string and concatenated when setting val + oldval

```
console.log(typeof(val)) // string

val = parseInt(n.val());
```

You can also set the attribute by using the jQuery data method, the same way you're retrieving it to update the response element.

```
n.data('oldval', val + oldval);
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/aso1s0xz/

Answer (score 1):

There is already a great answer but here is solution without `data-oldval` as I don't see why is it needed in this case.

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function() {
  var response = parseInt($('.response').text());
  if(isNaN(response))response=0;
  var val = parseInt($('input').val());
  var sum = val+response;
  $('.response').text(sum);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To get dynamic Value Try JS, It will work perfectly

```
document.getElementById('element-id').getAttribute('data-oldval');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Data()` method in jQuery to set the value too:

```js
var response = $('.response');

$('body').on('click', '.btn', function() {
  var btn = $(this),
    t = btn.parent('.dummy'),
    n = t.find('input[type=number]'),
    val = n.val(),
    oldval = n.data('oldval');

  n.data('oldval', parseInt(val)+parseInt(oldval));

  response.text(n.data('oldval'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dummy">
  <input type="number" value="1" data-oldval="0">
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Add</button>
</div>

<div class="response"></div>
```